# ftp tug org tarballs and snapshots

Tags: texlive, distributions

## 1.

On tug.org FTP (ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2014/) there are four tar.xz:

```
*-bin.tar.xz        (precompilled bins for many platforms)
*-sources.tar.xz    (sources for making bins)
*-devsources.tar.xz (???)
*-extra.tar.xz      (???)
*-texmf.tar.xz      (???)
```

- What are 'devsources' and 'extra' and 'texmf' archives?

## 2.

These two tarballs also available in another folder are needed to install tree and future update tlmgr:

```
ftp://tug.org/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
ftp://tug.org/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
```

- First is installer (netinstaller, more specific) and second is tlmgr-updater, isn't it?

## 3.

I have used '*-sources.tar.xz' to build my own binaries (custom) and 'install-tl-unx.tar.gz' to install TexLive.

- What should I download to install TexLive by install-tl script without the internet? 
  Maybe iso-image? or rsync some dir? (I means 'current' version).

Comment: It might be an idea to ask on the texlive mailing list instead.

Comment: thanks, but i can't subscribe to this...

Comment: erh, everybody can subscribe to the texlive mainling list, see http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live